# Eventlet and Python daemon, Foo not called?

Tags: python, queue, coroutine, eventlet

I am trying to build a Python deamon which listen to a queue (Redis Kombu).
Grab the task and spawn a greenthread to process this task.

I can receive the task and consume it without trouble but when I try to spawn a GreenThread with eventlet it does not seem to be doing anything at all.

No print, no logging is shown.

```
class agent(Daemon):
    """
    Agent
    """
    def run(self):  
        # Setup connection
        mainLogger.debug('Connecting to Redis')
        connection = BrokerConnection(
                        hostname=agentConfig['redis_host'],
                        transport="redis",
                        virtual_host=agentConfig['redis_db'],
                        port=int(agentConfig['redis_port']))
        connection.connect()

        # Create an eventlet pool of size 5
        pool = eventlet.GreenPool(5)
        q = connection.SimpleQueue("myq")
        while True:
            try:
               message = q.get(block=True, timeout=1)
               print "GOT A MESSAGE FROM Q !"
               pool.spawn_n(self.foo, 'x')
               print "END SPAWN !"
            except Empty:
               mainLogger.debug('No tasks, going to sleep')
               time.sleep(1)


    def foo(self, x):
        mainLogger.debug('\o/')
        print "HELLO FROM SPAWN"
```

Anything I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to call eventlet.monkey_patch() for sleep() call to trigger context switching.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `eventlet.sleep` as described here:

http://eventlet.net/doc/basic_usage.html#eventlet.sleep